# What is this Path code doing?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I am looking at some example code for [Expanding Item Renders in Datagrid](http://flexponential.com/2009/07/18/expanding-item-renderers-in-a-datagroup-or-list/) and I don't understand the line of code below:

```
Path data="M 0 0 L 8 0 L 4 6 L 0 0 Z"
```

I know it is defining the path used to define the triangle graphic but I don't understand how it is doing that. I've tried fiddling with the data but it still isn't making sense.
Can anyone shed some light on what this line is doing?

[image]

---

```
<s:Path data="M 0 0 L 8 0 L 4 6 L 0 0 Z" 
        top="3" left="3" rotation.up="-90" rotation="-90" 
        rotation.upAndSelected="0" rotation.overAndSelected="0" 
        rotation.downAndSelected="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="0x999999" color.over="0x000000" color.overAndSelected="0x000000" />
    </s:fill>
</s:Path>
```

Comment: `M 0 0 L 8 0 L 4 6 L 0 0 Z` = Move to 0,0 line to 8,0 line to 4,6 line to 0,0. I forgot what Z is. Probably some kind of "end"-thingy.

Comment: Yeah Z means "Zero" so you return to the first coordinate (0,0) defined by M 0 0. It just means "finish the path" :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so digging around a bit after the tip from @DodgerThud I found the documentation for [defining paths in mxml](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS5B6A8436-0FF5-4029-8524-C7C1106C483D.html)